# Replacing n with 2n in asymptotic bounds

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics, space-complexity, lower-bounds, probabilistic-algorithms

I am going through [Normal Subgroup Reconstruction and Quantum Computation Using Group Representations](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~amnon/Papers/HRT.stoc00.pdf) by Hallgren et al.

In the proof of the theorem $6$ of the paper on page 632, the authors go on proving the difference between the probabilities of sampling all irreps, $|p - q|_1$ of a subgroup inside the symmetric group $S_n$.

[image]

I want to compute the same bound for the symmetric group $S_{2 n}$. Should I just replace the $n$ in $2^{-\Omega(n)}$ and make it $2^{-\Omega(2n)} = 2^{-\Omega(n)}$?

Or, do I have to work it out from the scratch as follows?

$$
| p - q|_1 = \sum_\rho | p_\rho - q_\rho|
 \nonumber\\
  \le \sum_\rho \frac{d_\rho}{\left(2 n\right)!} 2^{O\left( n\right)}  n^{\frac{n}{2}}
  \nonumber\\
   \le \sum_\rho \frac{\sqrt{\left(2n\right)!}}{\left(2 n\right)!} 2^{O\left( n\right)}  n^{\frac{n}{2}}
    \nonumber\\
     \le  \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  n^{\frac{n}{2}}}{\sqrt{\left(2 n\right)!}} 
        \nonumber\\
            =  \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  n^{\frac{n}{2}}\sqrt{\left(2 n\right)!}}{\sqrt{\left(2 n\right)!}\sqrt{\left(2 n\right)!}} 
                    \nonumber\\
            =  \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  n^{\frac{n}{2}}\sqrt{\left(2 n\right)!}}{\left(2 n\right)!}
\nonumber\\
= \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  n^{\frac{n}{2}}\sqrt{\left(2 n\right)^{2n}}}{\left(2 n\right)!}
\nonumber\\
= \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  n^{\frac{n}{2}}\left(2 n\right)^{n}}{\left(2 n\right)!}
\nonumber\\
= \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  n^{\frac{n}{2}}n^{n}}{\left(2 n\right)!}
\nonumber\\
= \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  n^{\frac{3n}{2}}}{\left(2 n\right)!}
\nonumber\\
= \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  n^{\frac{3n}{2}}}{\left(2 n\right)^{\left(2 n\right)}}
\nonumber\\
= \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  n^{\frac{3n}{2}}}{ n^{2 n}}
\nonumber\\
= \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  }{ n^{\frac{n}{2}}}
\nonumber\\
= \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  }{ 2^{-\frac{n}{2}} n^{\frac{n}{2}}}
\nonumber\\
= \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  }{  \frac{n}{2}^{\frac{n}{2}}}
\nonumber\\
\le \frac{2^{O\left( n\right)}  }{  \left(\frac{n}{2}\right)!}
\nonumber\\
\lll 2^{-\Omega \left(n\right)}
$$

Comment: Are you asking whether $\Omega(n) = \Omega(2n)$, or whether that ansatz is correct?

Comment: @Raphael, I know that $\Omega(n) = \Omega(2n)$. I would like to know if I can just put this in the asymptotic bound or I have to prove it from the scratch when $n$ is replaced by $2 n$.

Comment: The provided bound ignores exponential terms, so I don't think you'll gain anything by moving from $n$ to $2n$.

Comment: @Raphael, that's correct. But in my case, the input symmetric group is $S_{2n}$. So, I have to determine the bound for $2 n$.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics we have the substitution principle. If a certain statement is true, then it also holds if you replace all occurrences of $n$ by some other expression, as long as that other expression has the same type as $n$. In particular, you can substitute $2n$ for $n$ and deduce that $|p-q|_1 \lll 2^{-\Omega(2n)}$. You can then conclude that $|p-q|_1 \lll 2^{-\Omega(n)}$, using the definition of $\Omega$.

Comment: That can not possible hold for *all* statements. Take "$n$ is even", for instance. Flat (in)equalities should work out, though. I'm wary about equations involving Landau terms, though, since e.g. $(n-1)! \in o(n!)$, so one side of an "equality" may "simplify" (e.g. $2^{n-1} \in \Theta(2^n)$) but the other not.

Comment: That's right, if the (universally quantified) statement "$n$ is even" were true, so would "$n+1$ is even".  For the proof, see here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/14137/why-are-universal-introduction-and-existential-elimination-valid-inference-rules.

Comment: Oh dear, my bad for commenting before breakfast. :D My concern about Landau terms stand, though. Maybe they are unfounded.